# Destination and Start in on a batch

Tags: batch

On a normal windows shortcut we have the Destination field and the Start in field.

Can I do those on a batch ?

.

Complicators:

Windows is on C:

The application is on E:

The Start in folder is on L:

.

The program I have uses the Start In field to look for files it saved (through the program's open dialog)

I **cannot** do the following:

```
cd /d E:\Program\

start program.exe
```

Because in this case, the program will run and will look for the saved files on E:\Program, as I have **not stated** anywhere the Start In folder (and people dumb down my question when I ask how to state it)

Comment: improve your question, isnt clear what exacly you need.

Comment: "Start in" will be whatever the current working directory is for the command shell, and the "Destination" would be the full path to the program you want to run.  What *exactly* do you need to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
start "" /d c:\somefolder "E:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 2.0\Parametric\bin\parametric.exe"
```

Sets the startup folder.

Comment: Yes, man !
It worked perfectly ! . . .

Would you explain the differences between your script and Mokubai's, when you find some free time ?
I'm intrigued by those empty quotes, in special... 


Thank you and everyone here that tried to help

Comment: Empty quotes are due to a bug in the parsing code where it assumes the first quoted string MUST be the window title. Noone cares about the window title so we leave it blank but we have to put it in if we want to quote a pathname.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is this:

```
cd /D L:\WhateverFolderYouWant
start E:\Program\program.exe
```

The directory you `cd` to is the current working directory that the program will use as its "Start In" directory.  If you give the full path of the program you want to run then it will run that program with the current working directory properly set.

In short, **do not** `cd` to the directory of the program, `cd` to the directory you want it to think of as the "Start In" directory.

Comment: Mokubai, It did not work. A CMD window opens, the cursor goes to the L:\WhateverFolder>, and the chosen program (or any other tested) does not run (I've paid attention to the details, like quotes on spaced paths, etc).     .     .     .     .     


I've recently messed with my environment variables, but then I restored (supposedly). Is there a variable critical for your code to work ?

Comment: No special variable that I'm aware of, can you show the full path of the program you are running?

Comment: Sure: The program in question is Parametric Creo: "E:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 2.0\Parametric\bin\parametric.exe". This program is a little more complicated than simply "run the executable an voila". That's why I tried other programs, but they all behave the same: not launching. Doesn't matter the partition or path of the program (C or E).
`cd /d L:\Projetos\Creo

start "E:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 2.0\Parametric\bin\parametric.exe"
`